# Getting inconsistent heap corruption for int array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-corruption

I am trying out the following program, and I am getting a heap corruption, which is expected.
Following is the code below:

```
int main()
{
    int A[] = { 2,4,16,32,0,0,0,0 };
    int B[] = { 5,17,31,35 };
    int i = 0, j = 0,k=0;
    int length = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int* temp = new int[length];
    while (k<length && A[k]!=0)
    {
        if (A[i] < B[j])
        {
            temp[k] = A[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[k] = B[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    //copythe remaining items in A[] into temp.
    while (i < length && A[i] != 0)
    {
        temp[k] = A[i];
        i++; k++;
    }
    //copy the remaining items in B[] into temp.
    while (j < length)
    {
        temp[k] = B[j];
        j++; k++;
    }
    cout << "the sorted array is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        cout << temp[i] << ", ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The heap corruption occurs, because I am writing out of bounds of the array `temp`. 
In my opinion, the heap corruption should have occurred at line 7244, where I assign B[j] to temp[k] - and k exceeds `length` (i.e. 8) - as highlighted below:

[image]

But, the heap corruption occurs much later, at line 7250 - where I attempt to `cout<<temp[0]`. -

[image]

I have a couple of questions:

1. Why does the heap corruption occur at trying to read `temp[0]` - since everything should be fine while attempting to read `temp[0]`?
2. Why does the heap corruption not occur at line 7244 itself, where I am assigning `B[j]` to `temp[k]` and `k` exceeds `length`.
3. Why is the heap corruption intermittent. I hit the heap corruption 4-5 times in the begining, but am not hitting it now?

Comment: You don't reset k here:  //copythe remaining items in A[] into temp.
    while (i < length && A[i] != 0)
    {
        temp[k] = A[i];
        i++; k++;
    } or do an additional check for it.

Comment: Although I am able to run this fine on an online c++ compiler. http://cpp.sh/ and the output is: the sorted array is: 2, 4, 5, 16, 32, 17, 31, 35.

Comment: You probably also need these checks while (i < length && A[i] != 0 && k < length) and  while (j < length && k < length) add the k < length in those conditions

Comment: are you sure, you didn't change anything and the heap corruption error just gone automatically? because it seems the shared program is ok!

Comment: Have you tried running it in GDB and stepping through to to see what is happening?

Comment: @MdGolamRahmanTushar - yes, I didn't change anything and the heap corruption disappeared automatically. The only thing I did was, run another heap corruption program to narrow down the issue. The program I ran did not repro the heap corruption. And after that, the program I shared here also stopped giving me the heap corruption.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons - not yet. But will try out GDB (once I get a repro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing past the bounds of an array is always Undefined Behavior. That being said, nothing bad is guaranteed to happen when you cause Undefined Behavior. The heap corruption only *maybe* occurs, because whether or not it occurs depends on where temp happened to be allocated relative to the data structures that make up the heap.

That being said, when heap corruption occurs, it occurs at the line you indicated, where `temp[k] = B[j]`. The program doesn't notice that the heap is corrupted until you try printing out `temp` using `cout`, and the reason for that is heap corruption is only "noticed" when you try to do operations involving the heap (such as allocation or deletion). It's likely that `cout << temp[i] << '", "` does either allocation or deletion under the hood as part of the process of printing out `temp[i]`, and that's what causes the crash.